# Problema con bootstrap y menus

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un proyecto con una barra colapsable (sidebar) a la izquierda con un boton de toggle.
Tambien agregue un barra de navegacion estatica arriba, y obtengo el siguiente error de jquery:

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mCustomScrollbar is not a function**

El codigo es:

```js
   $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
            theme: "minimal"
        });

        $('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function () {
            // hide sidebar
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
            // hide overlay
            $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
        });

        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            // open sidebar
            $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
            // fade in the overlay
            $('.overlay').addClass('active');
            $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
            $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
        });
```

Tambien adjunto imagen de como se ve en Opera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no entiendo porque en el menu de usuario se ven dos flechas hacia abajo en vez de una.

Para el proyecto me base en:

[Bootstrap](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar)

El codigo html completo es:

```html
<nav class = "navbar" style="background-color: lightblue;" role = "navigation">
         <div class = "navbar-header">
         
            <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">GESTION WEB</a>
          <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn">
         </div>
         <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <?php echo " " .$_SESSION ['nombre']; ?>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        
                        
                        <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Cerrar Sesion</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
             
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">

        <div id="dismiss">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="content">
ggkgkjgjkgjgjg
     
    </div>
    <!-- Dark Overlay element -->
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Bueno lo solucione incluyendo los scripts correctamente, pero me queda el menu de arriba asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir el header y el nombre de usuario centrados no a los costados. Lo demas va  a la perfeccion, el sidebar se despliega sobre el copntenido y demas.

Comment: La página del tutorial usa la versión 4 de Bootstrap, ¿estás utilizando en tu proyecto la misma versión?

Comment: Si, ya corrobore eso, inclui correctamente los scripts..Muchas gracias.